# how to do head-tracing in android accurately?

Tags: android, opengl-es, virtual-reality

I want to load an object using opengles and view it when rotating the device, as if there is a real object floating in real world.
For example, when I turn my head right, the object in the screen move left.
I'm using the android magnectic and accelorate sensor , but the result is hardly good.
What's the general way of doing this VR like app, Just like google cardboard?
Is there any better way?It is highly appreciated if there is any example, thank you!